# Fetch data from json like load more using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I am noob at javascript and doing practice for improving my skills.

I made one sample project and fetched data from json using getJSON.

It worked fine but what I want is to show 3rd index data first and rest onclick of loadMore button.

like First I will have "3 list item" populated with json after that I would need every 2 li to get populated on loadMore click...here is my json array

```
[
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
{
"imagepath" : "sample url",
"heading" : "sample heading",
"details" : "sample details"
},
]
```

and here is sample code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#fetchit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"one.json",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success :function(){
                        //alert('bf c')
                        $('.hold').empty();
                        $.getJSON("one.json",function(data){
                            $.each(data ,function(i,value){
                                var list ="<li>" + "<img src'" + value.imagepath + "' alt=''/>" + "<span>" + value.heading + "</span>" + "<span>" + value.details + "</span>" 
                            $('.hold').append(list)
                            })
                        })
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,status,error){
                        alert(xhr.status)
                    }
                })
            })
        });
```

this code is fetching whole json at one click but i want to parse it or load it in parts on click.
please help me in this using ajax getJSON or javascript. I am unable to make the logic of loadMore, I know we have to do this by some counter...

Comment: what have you tried so far? just showing the json won't encourage people to help ... in my opinion - load more would only be relevant, to save traffic in the beginning - so if your json contains already all data - why not show it right from the beginning? if your first request only retrieves the first 3 objects, then i guess, you need some server side logic to generate the json on your request. as a request parameters, you could use the .length() function to know how many entries you already have and add a second variable to tell the server how many objects you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/8erwrha2/

**JS:-**

```
var json = [{
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}, {
    "imagepath": "sample url",
        "heading": "sample heading",
        "details": "sample details"
}];

jQuery(function ($) {
    $.each(json, function (i, value) {
        var list = "<li class='hidden' >" + "<img src'" + value.imagepath + "' alt=''/>" + "<span>" + value.heading + "</span>" + "<span>" + value.details + "</span>"
        $('.hold').append(list);
    });

    function loadMore(){
        $(".hold .hidden").slice(0,2).removeClass("hidden");
    }

    loadMore();

    $("#btnLoadMore").on("click",loadMore);        

});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="hold"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnLoadMore" value="Load More"/>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```